# Barracuda VPN client for linux 5.2.2 fails to process onetimepwd parameter

Tags: linux, vpn

I use barracudavpn for linux version 5.2.2.
According to the usage help I should be able to provide an OTP via the `onetimepwd` parameter.

```
barracudavpn --start --login <login-name> --serverpwd <password for login name> --onetimepwd <one-time password>
```

But it seems to be ignored as I always get "OTP-required" as a result. Nevertheless it works via the barracudavpn TUI.

Edit: As the official barracudavpn documentation seems to be outdated, I want to share the `help` output here:

```
$ barracudavpn --help
usage:
-----

<basename> [options]

where options may be:
-s  --start     Start VPN tunnel
-p  --stop      Stop VPN tunnel
-t  --status    Show tunnel status
-k  --keypwd    Password for local key
-r  --serverpwd Server password
-o  --onetimepwd    One-time password
-l  --login     Server login (user, pwd authentication)
-c  --config    Pathname to config.
-V  --version   Print VPN client version.
-v  --verbose   Show debug output
-h  --help      Shows this help information


Scripting examples:
-------------------
1. personal license authentication:
    barracudavpn --start --keypwd <license-password>
2. X509 authentication
    barracudavpn --start --keypwd <cert/key-password>
3. X509 + user/password authentication
    barracudavpn --start --keypwd <cert/key-password> --login <login-name> --serverpwd <password for login name>
4. user/password authentication
    barracudavpn --start --login <login-name> --serverpwd <password for login name>
5. user/password authentication
    barracudavpn --start --login <login-name> --serverpwd <password for login name> --onetimepwd <one-time password>
```

Comment: The [Barracuda Campus article](https://campus.barracuda.com/product/networkaccessclient/doc/46206586/how-to-establish-a-vpn-connection-using-barracuda-vpn-client-for-linux/) does not list the onetimepwd parameter.

Comment: Right, I think this page is outdated. It has been updated 2021-10-11 and version 5.2.2 is from 2022-09-14 (at least the versions page has been updated at this time)